# Truncate the percentage in the tooltip of the pie charts

Tags: asp.net, pie-chart, fusioncharts

How to set the precision on the calculated percentage in fusion pie charts. 
My pie chart attributes  as

```
xmlData.Append("<chart showValues='1' formatNumber='1' showBorder='0' bgColor='FFFFFF' manageLabelOverflow='1' formatNumberScale='0'>");
  foreach (DataRow drRecord in dataResult.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    xmlData.Append("<set label='" + drRecord["Analyze"].ToString() + "' value='" + drRecord["BSLN_RVN"].ToString() + "' />");
                }
```

I tried adding decimalPrecision = '1'. It changes both the percentage value and the value in the chart to single decimal precision. Is there any property to set the precision only to the calculated percentage in pie charts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide the raw value in the `toolText='text_here'` attribute.

It is explained very well in the [FusionCharts Documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?ChartSS/Column2D.html#Anchor20).

Comment: how to set the tooltext for all chart divided areas. Its calculated automatically..